# Does F# internally make the code run in parallel by default?

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, f#, task-parallel-library

I have a simple question regarding the parallel processing in F#.
Below is the my code to calculate the sum of 1^2+2^2+...+100^2 (which is pretty simple problem, really). From what I understand is that, the program creates a second list (by square each item in the first list,and put them into the second list), then it takes the sum of all items in the second list. Does the program internally do the squaring of every item in the original list in parallel ? Or the process is merely sequential ? If the latter is the case, how can I make the code to run in parallel ?

```
let mySum = 
[1..100]
|>Seq.map (fun n -> n*n)
|>Seq.sum
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No F# doesn't make the code run in parallel by default.
Also the list is by definition a data structure that has sequential access to its members.
You could run the code in parallel using for example F# Array.Parallel module:

```
let myParSum = 
    [|1..1000|]
    |> Array.Parallel.map (fun n -> n * n)
    |> Array.sum
```

or use standard .NET [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: a bit off the original question: how would you suggest to measure the CPU time on the calculations of the Sum in those two methods. In other .NET languages such as VB.NET or C# I often use "stopwatch". Does F# have its own built-it tool / function to do the same thing ?

Comment: You can use `#time` directive in F# interactive window. See reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx